# How to make a persistent virtual device in the Smart Home sample?

Tags: actions-on-google

I just downloaded and ran [the sample from here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs). It is working but whenever I connect to the web site (https://something.ngrok.io/) or even refreshing it takes a lot of time andd the Node.js console shows it is getting a lot of "/bower_components", also even thought I have log in with the same account ("rick/oldman"), previously-added devices are gone.

I want to add a persistent simple virtual light, so I saw datastore.js, and either the documentation is missing or I could not find it. The only thing I could find was the comment.

```
/**
 * Structure of Data
 * {
 *   <uid>: {
 *     <device id>: {
 *       properties: {
 *         <property name>: <property value>,
 *         <property name>: <property value>
 *       },
 *       states: {
 *         <state name>: <state value>,
 *         <state name>: <state value>
 *       }
 *     },
 *     <device id>: {...}
 *   },
 *   <uid>: {
 *     <device id>: {...},
 *     <device id>: {...},
 *     <device id>: {...}
 *   },
 *   ...
 * }
 */
```

There was no sample, so I inferred from the logs (created a device on the web site), and created one like this, but this device does not show up.

```
const config = require('./config-provider');
const Data = {
  "f9b2dc04-2518-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b":{
    "light1":{
      "states":{
        "on": false,
        "online":true
      },
      "properties":{  
        "type":"action.devices.types.LIGHT",
        "traits":["action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
        "attributes":{  
            "temperatureMinK":2000,
            "temperatureMaxK":6500
        },
        "name":{  
            "defaultNames":[  
              "Fake Light"
            ],
            "name":"Fake Light 1",
            "nicknames":[  
              "fake lamp"
            ]
        },
        "willReportState":false,
        "roomHint":"",
        "deviceInfo":{  
            "manufacturer":"Fake Home Provider",
            "model":"fake1234",
            "swVersion":"1.0.0",
            "hwVersion":"1.0"
        },
        "customData":{  
            "smartHomeProviderId":"thisisfakesuperfake"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I am not sure if the data is correct or not; I could not find any sample for that. What do I need to do to have a persistent virtual device and prevent re-downloading the bower components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was introduced to make it easier for testing different configurations. The behavior happens [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/blob/24d85ba28e29e8d113108fb94fc11e089b9c25db/smart-home-provider/cloud/smart-home-provider-cloud.js#L154) in the sample code:

`app.post('/smart-home-api/reset-devices', function (request, response)`

This behavior may be a bit weird depending on how people use the sample, so I have added a new configuration option: [`Config.enableReset`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/blob/24d85ba28e29e8d113108fb94fc11e089b9c25db/smart-home-provider/cloud/config-provider.js#L21).

By default, it will be true. However, by setting that to false it should persist the devices across page refreshes.

As for Bower, it should not be downloading the files every time, I think those logs are just noting that the files are being "Gotten" from the server. I believe the server caches the responses, so you may be seeing status codes in the 300 range instead of 200.